# Deserializing nested json object c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a nested json object, like this,

```
  "where": {
      "operator": "AND",
      "left": {
        "operator": "=",
        "$fieldRef": "requestor",
        "value": "@me"
      },
      "right": {
        "operator": "=",
        "$fieldRef": "state",
        "value": "Closed"
      }
    },
```

I would like to deserialize this in C#, but the problem is that the object can more larger depending on the user, the object can as follows,

and even like this,

```
"where": {
      "operator": "OR",
      "left": {
        "operator": "STARTSWITH",
        "$fieldRef": "id"
      },
      "right": {
        "operator": "OR",
        "left": {
          "operator": "STARTSWITH",
          "$fieldRef": "orgId"
        },
        "right": {
          "operator": "AND",
          "left": {
            "operator": "STARTSWITH",
            "$fieldRef": "firstname"
          },
          "right": {
            "operator": "STARTSWITH",
            "$fieldRef": "lastname"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: are you trying to deserialize odata ?

Comment: No, just deserialize to classes....

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the most popular library for this: [json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Then you can use the built in Visual studio parse tool for JSON to classes which is found found under: EDIT -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as classes.
This will generate the classes needed for you json.

Once you've added a reference to json.NET you can then run the following to deserialize:

```
RootObject deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Were "RootObject" is the top most class for you json structure.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the problem is the object is not fixed it can have more nested objects..